# Download file using Struts2 with a prompt

Tags: java, google-chrome, download, struts2, http-headers

I am downloading a file using `Struts2`. When I click on the button to downlaod the file, the file downloads and opens in Excel by itself rather I want it to download and when I right click on it I should be able to either open or save it. In `IE` and `Firefox` I get a window to open or save the file but in `Chrome` the file file opens in Excel by itself. Is there any way to have it in `Chrome` just like `Firefox` and `IE`

Action

```
public String viewReport() throws Exception {
    boolean returnReport;
    inputStream = new FileInputStream(DOCUSIGN_REPORT_FILE);

    try {
        returnReport = validateRequest();
        if (returnReport) {

        intgList = this.generateViewIntegrationReportData(getESignUIConfig());
        this.createCSVFile(intgList, DOCUSIGN_REPORT_FILE);

        } else {
            failureResponse(msgs, 400);
            return null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        msgs.add(new Message(ESignatureIntegrationMessageTypeEnum.MESSAGE_TYPE_ERROR, 
                    UiIntegrationKeyConstants.UI_INTEGRATION_ERROR_CODE_500, UiIntegrationKeyConstants.UI_INTEGRATION_ERROR_TEXT_SERVICE_ERROR));
        failureResponse(msgs, 500);
        return null;
    }

    return UiIntegrationKeyConstants.REPORT_REPSONSE;
}
```

Struts.xml

```xml
<action name="*Integration" method="{1}" class="foo.bar.ESignatureIntegrationAction">
    <result name="success" type="tiles">integrationView</result>  
    <result name="reportResponse" type="stream"> 
        <param name="contentType">application/text/csv</param>
        <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>  
        <param name="contentDisposition">
            attachment;filename="DocuSignEnvelopeReport.csv"
        </param> 
        <param name="bufferSize">4096</param>
    </result>  
</action>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prompt asking if opening the file with a desktop application or saving it is given by the `contentDisposition` HTTP header set to `attachment` (that you have set). On the contrary, `inline` would have tried to open the file with a browser plugin, without asking anything.

That said, the reason behind your problem is that you (or someone with access to your computer) have previously instructed Chrome to **always open files of this type**, and this is why it doesn't ask you anymore about what to do:

[image]

The solution is to **clear this option** from the settings

<kbd>Customize and Control Google Chrome</kbd> <kbd>Settings</kbd> <kbd>+ Show advanced settings</kbd> <kbd>Clear auto-opening settings</kbd>

[image]

Comment: You are awesome Andrea. You understood my question and without any further investigation you answered what I was looking for. I was told that it is a browser behavior but no one knew how to fix it. Thank you so much once again.